# Parsing problem -- can two clauses share a single predicate?

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension, coordination

> この中の４９０万人ぐらいは、近くの国に逃げて難民になりました。**ヨーロッパで難民の申請をしている人は１２０万人ぐらい、国の中で逃げている人は６３０万人います**。
>   Around 4.9 million of these (people) have escaped to nearby countries and become refugees. **As for the people who have applied for refugee status in Europe, approximately 1.2 million, there are 6.3 million people escaping to these countries**.

Please help me to parse the sentence in bold. My translation doesn't make sense. This is my understanding so far:

1) So the topic is ヨーロッパで難民の申請をしている人 people who have applied for refugee status in Europe

2) ６３０万人います there are 6.3 million (people who have applied)

But I can't make １２０万人ぐらい、国の中で逃げている人は fit into this structure.

Then I thought maybe it is two separate sentences:

> ヨーロッパで難民の申請をしている人は１２０万人ぐらい
>   (there are) approximately 1.2 million people who have applied for refugee status in Europe

and

> 国の中で逃げている人は６３０万人います
>   There are 6.3 million people who are escaping to these countries.

But that first sentence isn't a sentence. There's no predicate. Maybe it assumes the predicate at the end (いる)?

Also I think I'm mistranslating 国の中で because I thought that should be 'among these countries' but that translation doesn't seem to fit.

I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010887021000/k10010887021000.html) is the original article.

> 戦争が始まった２０１１年から、全部で１２４０万人が自分の家に住むことができなくなりました。これはシリアの人口の半分以上です。この中の４９０万人ぐらいは、近くの国に逃げて難民になりました。ヨーロッパで難民の申請をしている人は１２０万人ぐらい、国の中で逃げている人は６３０万人います。

So among the 12.4 million Syrian people who were driven out of their home,

- 4.9M people went to nearby countries: 近くの国に逃げて難民になった
- 1.2M people went to European countries: ヨーロッパで難民の申請をしている
- The remaining 6.3M people are still in Syria: 国の中で逃げている

国の中で逃げている here means "to evacuate inside the country = Syria". 国の中で means "in the country." Why did you see "to"? で is a plain old place marker (="in/at") here.

In the last sentence, one main verb います is shared by both two topics marked with は. (「Aは120万人、Bは630万人います。」 ≒ 「Aは120万人いて、Bは630万人います。」）

My translation would be:

> There are approximately 1.2 million people who are applying for refugee status in Europe, and (there are) 6.3 million people who are evacuating inside their country.

Comment: "Why did I see "to"?": Well, since the previous 国 was referring to other countries, it never entered my mind that this one might be Syria itself. Also in the context, I never considered running away to the same country to be an option. Maybe I would have expected to see 自分の国. Anyway things are much clearer now. Thanks.